# How to change two elements in an uncountably infinite product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinite-product

I have an uncountable product, say

$$\prod_{i \in I}A_i$$

And i want to replace $A_{i_0}$ and $A_{i_1}$ by $B_{i_0}$ and $B_{i_1}$ respectively. However I know that

$$\left( \prod_{i \in I, \ i \neq i_0, i_1}A_i \right) \times B_{i_0} \times B_{i_1}$$

is not the right way to do this because there is a slight problem with the order of this product.

I could define $C_i$ which equals to $A_i$ for every $i$ except $i_0$ and $i_1$, but I am wondering if there's an easy way to do it.

Comment: Are you taking the product of sets or numbers?

Comment: Sets $%%%%%%%%$

Answer (score 2):

No, that is the only way to do it. (Your remark on order is true.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Since the OP qualified he is talking about the product of sets, no such construction as below is possible. This leaves no other option but to define a new sequence.

---

Since $I$ is uncountable we would need additional properties for $A_i$ to hold. For example if $I$ is ordered and the products $\prod_{i<i_0} A_i, \prod_{i_0<i<i_1} A_i$ and $\prod_{i>i_1} A_i$ all exist and are finite, you may write what you initially stated:
$$P = \prod_{i<i_0} A_i \cdot B_{i_0} \cdot \prod_{i_0<i<i_1} A_i \cdot B_{i_1} \cdot \prod_{i>i_1} A_i = \prod_{i\in I, i\ne i_0, i\ne i_1} A_i \cdot B_{i_0} \cdot B_{i_1} < \infty$$

If we assume the index set was countable and $i_0 < i_1$, You could write
$$\prod_{i=1}^{i_0-1} A_i \cdot B_{i_0} \cdot \prod_{i=i_0+1}^{i_1-1} A_i \cdot B_{i_1} \cdot \prod_{i=i_1+1}^\infty A_i$$
Because the first terms are kept in order and constitute a finite product. It is essential that $I$ is countable for this to work. The statement is then also equivalent to
$$\prod_{i<i_1, i\ne i_0} A_i \cdot B_{i_0} \cdot B_{i_1} \cdot \prod_{i>i_1} A_i$$
Since the first terms again are finite products.

Comment: Check out comments on OP post, this doesn't apply to the question.

Comment: @DanZimm Thanks for the ping.

Comment: Nonetheless, if these were numbers you could just take out $2$ of the terms, and then multiply them in at the end (2 terms can't make an infinite product diverge), thus you could literally just replace them here.

Comment: @DanZimm Not so sure about uncountable products there (splitting is very problematic) especially they can make a divergent product converge leading to a $\infty\cdot 0$ situation on the RHS

Comment: Assume $\Pi_{i \in I} a_i$ converges. Then $\frac{\Pi_{i \in I} a_i}{a_{i_0} a_{i_1}}$ converges so $\Pi_{i \in I, i \neq i_0, i_1} a_i$ converges

Comment: @DanZimm Nothing against that, but assume $\prod_i A_i$ diverges and $B_{i_0} = 0$ At least you need a special case for degenerate products ($\prod A_i = 0, B_{i_j} = 0$).

Comment: Sure, but this is a different question, I suppose I didn't interpret the initial question the same way you did ;P

Comment: @DanZimm Since the OP specified his intents now, there's not much to worry about the "old" answer. Unless you spot any mistakes in it ;)